# When switching from Glitch to RedHat Openshift, discord.js music command doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift, audio-player, discord.js

So I recently ran into this very weird problem. I've been using glitch.com to host my discord bot. The music command ran perfectly - the only npm packages I used were `discord.js`, `ytdl-core` and `youtube-search`. But as soon as I switched to RedHat Openshift, the music command just suddenly... failed. I get unhandled promise rejections saying "FFMPEG not found".

Here is my code:

```js
if (command.startsWith("play")) {
    let song = command.substr(4);
    if (queue[message.guild.id] == undefined) {
      queue[message.guild.id] = [];
    }
    queue[message.guild.id].push([song, message]);
    let recursivePlay = function() {
      let song = queue[message.guild.id].shift();
      ytsearch(
        song[0],
        {
          maxResults: 1,
          key: process.env.YTAPI
        },
        function(err, results) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          try {
            song[1].member.voiceChannel.join();
          } catch (e) {
            song[1].channel.send({
              embed: new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle("Queue")
                .setDescription(
                  "<@" +
                    song[1].author.id +
                    "> is not connected to a voice channel. Therefore, we must move on to the next song in the queue!"
                )
                .setTimestamp()
                .setColor("#961934")
            });
            if (queue[song[1].guild.id] != []) {
              recursivePlay();
            }
            return;
          }
          song[1].channel.send({
            embed: new Discord.RichEmbed()
              .setTitle("Now Playing")
              .setDescription(
                "Song [" +
                  results[0].title +
                  "](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" +
                  results[0].id +
                  ") is now playing, as requested by <@" +
                  song[1].author.id +
                  ">"
              )
              .setTimestamp()
              .setColor("#961934")
          });
          queue[song[1].guild.id].playing = true;
          song[1].member.voiceChannel.join();
          queue[
            song[1].guild.id
          ].dispatcher = song[1].guild.voiceConnection.playStream(
            ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + results[0].id, {
              filter: "audioonly"
            }),
            {
              passes: 1
            }
          );
          queue[song[1].guild.id].dispatcher.on("end", function() {
            song[1].guild.voiceConnection.disconnect();
            queue[song[1].guild.id].playing = false;
            if (queue[song[1].guild.id] != []) {
              recursivePlay();
            }
          });
        }
      );
    };
    if (!queue[message.guild.id].playing) {
      recursivePlay();
    } else {
      message.channel.send({
        embed: new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle("Queue")
          .setDescription("Song request `" + song + "` added to the queue.")
          .setFooter("Position: " + queue[message.guild.id].length)
          .setColor("#961934")
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you say switched to OpenShift, are you saying that you are deploying your NodeJS application which does this to OpenShift using its S2I builder to NodeJS? If yes, then likely the S2I image doesn't include FFMPEG tools in it.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't know that. Okay, thanks for helping!

Comment: Though, how do I add FFMPEG tools to the S2I image?

Comment: Have you confirmed first they are missing by using ``oc rsh`` to get into the running container and see if any programs/libraries for the package are installed?

Comment: If they are missing, you would need to create a derived version of the image with the additional packages installed. You would then run the S2I build with your custom S2I image instead of the default. Before can describe in more detail what to do, need you to work out what the missing operating system packages are.